# Update collection , convert fields to array

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I'm pretty new  in nosql world and i'd like to try the"geonear" (geospatial) feature in mongodb , i imported some data in this form :

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("549164b752c5c30b15bbc26a"),
   "ville":"Auenheim",
   "lat":"48,81",
   "lon":"8,01"
}
```

and i need to update all my data collection in this form :

{

```
  "_id":ObjectId("549164b752c5c30b15bbc26a"),
   "ville":"Auenheim",
   loc : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 8.01 , 48.81] }
```

}

Is there a way from an update query to do that with mongo ?
or should i use a php script(collection is huge..)

thanks fo help,
happy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through each document and change the format with a simple script. In the mongo shell, you would write something like

```
db.test.find({}, { "lat" : 1, "lon" : 1 }).forEach(function(doc) {
     db.test.update({ "_id" : doc._id },
                    {
                        "$unset" : { "lat" : 1, "lon" : 1 },
                        "$set" : { "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ doc.lon, doc.lat ] } }
                    })
})
```

You need to change your `lat` and `lon` to numbers, as well. I'm not sure if that was a typo or what, but you can do that as part of the function to, if need be. To make this faster, you can a [parallel collection scan](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/parallelCollectionScan/), which is supported in most drivers, to process all the documents using multiple threads.